# Why HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash returns different values from the same data?

Tags: c#, .net-core, hash, blockchain

I want to create hash from data sent in postman. I send some data and it works, it is added to the database. But when i want to post something next my Shipment which is in database is verified if it's hash is correct and then the hash that is saved in database is different from calculated.
Is there some difference when I post data from postman and when i read it from database?

```
public class BlockExtension : IBlock
{
    public byte[] CalculateHash(Shipment shipment)
    {
        var dataToHash = new DataToHash(shipment.Data, shipment.index, shipment.PrevHash, shipment.TimeStamp);

        using (SHA256 hash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
            Byte[] result = hash.ComputeHash(ObjectToByteArray(dataToHash));

            return result;
        }
    }

    private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(DataToHash data)
    {
        if (data == null)
            return null;

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
        {
            ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve
        };

        var result = JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(data, options);
        return result;
    }

    public Shipment CreateGenesisBlock(CreateShipmentCommand request)
    {
        var block = new Shipment()
        {
            ProductId = request.ProductId,
            index = 0,
            TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
            PrevHash = BitConverter.GetBytes('0'),
            Data = new Data()
            {
                PlaceOfArrivalId = request.Data.PlaceOfArrivalId,
                PlaceOfDepartureId = request.Data.PlaceOfDepartureId
            }
        };

        block.Hash = CalculateHash(block);

        return block;
    }

    public Shipment GetLatestBlock(Product product) => product.SupplyChain.Last();

    public bool IsChainValid(List<Shipment> shipments)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < shipments.Count; i++)
        {
            var currentBlock = shipments[i];
            var previousBlock = shipments[i - 1];


            if (!(currentBlock.Hash.SequenceEqual(CalculateHash(currentBlock))))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!currentBlock.PrevHash.SequenceEqual(previousBlock.Hash))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public List<Shipment> AddBlock(Shipment shipment, Product product)
    {
        shipment.PrevHash = GetLatestBlock(product).Hash;
        shipment.Hash = CalculateHash(shipment);
        product.SupplyChain.Add(shipment);

        return product.SupplyChain.ToList();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does anything have a current datetime in it?

Comment: @Neil Yes is it a problem? When I add there is current datetime, when I read from database there is data that I added before

Comment: If you are hashing data, and any part of that data changes, then the hash will be different.

Comment: "same data" and "includes current time" can't really be true at the same time. Please review your question and [edit] accordingly. Based on the comment it sounds like question should be "why hash of different values is different, how to ensure different data hashed to the same value" instead of what it says now.

Comment: is ``JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes`` using a deterministic / same order for properties in all runs?